# Fractions and cancellation

Tags: number-theory

Prove that fraction $(a+b)/(c+d)$ can't be cancelled (reduced) if $ad-bc=\pm1$.
I'm not sure how to approach this; I tried to somehow put that fraction to another form, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ natural numbers, integers?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid a+b$ and $p\mid c+d$.
Then
$$
p\mid (a+b)d-b(c+d)=ad-bc=\pm 1,
$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\,\ n\mid \color{#c00}{a+b},\,\ n\mid\color{#0a0}{c+d}.\ $  Reasoning *equationally* modulo $\,n\,$ we find

$\quad {\rm mod}\ n\!:\:\ \begin{align}\color{#c00}{a\equiv -b}\\ \color{#0a0}{d\equiv -c}\end{align} $ $\, \Rightarrow\: \pm1 \equiv \color{#c00}a\color{#0a0}d-bc\equiv(\color{#c00}{-b})(\color{#0a0}{-c})-bc\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid \pm1\!-\!0$